# No prometheus in Gitlab Omnibus

Tags: gitlab, prometheus

Setup: Ubuntu 14.04 with all recent updates,

Gitlab Omnibus version 11.7.3 (latest)

```
~$ sudo grep prometheus /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb

prometheus_monitoring['enable'] = true
prometheus['enable'] = true
prometheus['listen_address'] = ':9090'
```

The problem - browser cannot connect to http://localhost:9090, and logs are empty.

```
$ curl http://localhost:9090
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9090: Connection refused

$ sudo gitlab-ctl tail prometheus
==> /var/log/gitlab/prometheus/state <==

==> /var/log/gitlab/prometheus/current <==
```

`sudo netstat -tunlp` does not show port 9090

However, the prometheus process seems to be running:

```
$ ps ax | grep prometheus
 1358 ?        Ss     6:32 runsv prometheus
 1377 ?        S      0:35 svlogd -tt /var/log/gitlab/prometheus
 6935 ?        Ssl    0:02 /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/gitlab-workhorse -listenNetwork unix -listenUmask 0 -listenAddr /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/socket -authBackend http://localhost:8080 -authSocket /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/sockets/gitlab.socket -documentRoot /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public -pprofListenAddr  -prometheusListenAddr localhost:9229 -secretPath /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/.gitlab_workhorse_secret -config config.toml
25394 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto prometheus
```

Forgot to add, nginx, bundled with Gitlab is disabled. I use another nginx, installed from repositories.

Also tried restarting prometheus - no luck.

```
~$ sudo gitlab-ctl restart prometheus
ok: run: prometheus: (pid 32380) 0s

~$ curl -I http://localhost:9090
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9090: Connection refused
```

Update.

But now prometheus logs are not empty! Somehow its group was deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After restarting, prometheus logs were not empty! Somehow group `gitlab-prometheus` was deleted. After restoring the group, everything Ok.